# Adding """ at the beginning and end of a string?

Tags: python, string, formatting

Whenever I feed a string like `"Muhammed went to the store and said "Can I have some pickles please""` It seems to screw up how the string is handled since a `Can I have some pickles please` becomes invalid. So I thought adding """ at both sides of it would surely fix it, if there are any better solutions to this, I'm open to it.

Comment: "feed"? Is this input data or source code? If source code, you can use single quotes interchangeably with double quotes (`'xxx "yyy"'`) or escape the double quotes (`"xxx \"yyy\""`).

Comment: by feed I mean input data. Sometimes I'll be entering a whole file, so going through it and entering back slashes isn't really an option

Comment: Where does the string come from and how do you use it? Why don't you read it from an external file instead of putting it in the source code?

Comment: It sounds like you're putting input data in your source code. Don't do that; use a file or stdin instead.

Comment: @Nicholas: You should put this in an answer instead of a comment. It's the only right answer and the only one that would get my upvote.

Comment: Done. I always get confused about whether to make a tentative answer into an answer or a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just escape the inner quotes:

```
"Muhammed went to the store and said \"Can I have some pickles please\""
```

or use single quotes

```
'Muhammed went to the store and said "Can I have some pickles please"'
```

Comment: I should've been clear, sometimes the string will be too large to go to ever instance where there's a backslash, is there any other way around this?

Comment: @Louis93: What do you mean by "too large"? The resulting string will be the correct size, it's only the source code that will be slightly longer.

Comment: I mean I might enter a paragraph that contains a lot of both speech-marks and single inverted commas. In a case impossible for me to go over it and enter backslashes near them, how would I go about changing it all into a lump of string without having the punctuation interfere?

Comment: @Louis93: In that case you would use the triple-quote syntax as you mentioned. Is this not working for you for some reason?

Comment: Well, supposing it ends in a speech mark, it doesn't work out. The answer above you mentions this as well.

Comment: @Louis: Well, you can work around it with something like `"""i said "hello""" '"'`.

Comment: "I might enter a paragraph that contains a lot of both speech-marks and single inverted commas...." Don't do that. Read it from a file.

Answer (score 4):

Pick one:

```
'Muhammed went to the store and said "Can I have some pickles please"'
"Muhammed went to the store and said \"Can I have some pickles please\""
```

You cant fix it like this

```
"""Muhammed went to the store and said "Can I have some pickles please""""
```

because then you would have he string `Muhammed went to the store and said "Can I have some pickles please` with a single extra `"` at the end.

In general you can also use

```
'''Muhammed went to the store and said "Can I have some pickles please"'''
```

instead, but that would be pointless with your example.

Comment: What if the string is too large to just go to and put back-slashes?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're putting input data in your source code. Don't do that; use a file or `sys.stdin` instead.